# search for a string in array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this. I get this from a server's response :

So sometimes the array is like this :

```
$array = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Message: Thanks for all 
        [1] => Response: Goodbye
        [2] => 
        [3] =>  inactive
        [4] =>  active call
        [5] =>  active channels
        [6] =>  Hello                                             
        [7] =>  Hi
        [8] =>  yes     
        [9] =>  no      
    )
```

and sometimes it's like this :

```
$array = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Message: Thanks for all 
        [1] => Response: Goodbye
        [2] => 
        [3] => SessionTV: 2019-06-24T17:29:53.925+0530
        [4] => SessionTV: 2019-06-24T17:29:53.925+0530
        [5] => SessionTV: 2019-06-24T17:29:53.925+0530
        [6] => Event: 0
        [7] =>  active channels
        [8] =>  Hello                                             
        [9] =>  Hi
        [10] =>             
    )
```

This is what I tried :

```
if (in_array("Event:", $array)) 
  { 

        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
  } 
else
  { 

        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
        array_shift($minarr);
    }
```

But this doesn't work.

Expected output in both cases is :

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Hello                                             
    [1] =>  Hi
    [2] =>  yes   
    [3] =>  no        
)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Hello                                             
    [1] =>  Hi
    [2] =>        
)
```

So basically I just shift some rows from the array if it contains the string `Event:` and shift some other rows if it doesn't contain the string `Event:` .

How do I search for a string in an array like this?

Comment: `Event:`  doesn't exist in the first type of the array. So how did you come up with it's result like that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So basically you want to get all elements *after* the `active channels` value?

Comment: So you always want occurances [8] and [9] from the original array regardless of whether the array contains an occurance with `Event:` in it or not? **Is that right??**

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your goal instead of showing your solution and expecting us to understand your issue?

Comment: What @Qirel said. You just want everything after "active channels"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to obtain all values after `active channel`, and assuming that all values in the array is numerically indexed, then you can find the `active channels` element with `array_search()`. This returns the key of that element (first occurrence). Use this with `array_slice()` to slice away those first elements. Add 1 to the return of `array_search()`, as you want to remove that as well.

```php
$key = array_search('active channels', $array);
$output = array_slice($array, $key + 1);
```

If your array is not numerically indexed, you can fetch the values by using `array_values()` first, which is the same array, just numerically indexed.

```php
$array = array_values($array);
$key = array_search('active channels', $array);
$output = array_slice($array, $key + 1);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/UVUsr

Answer (score 1):

you can use `array_walk` with `strpos` , the solution is based on the provided input

```
$res = [];
array_walk($array, function($v, $k) use (&$res){
  if(strpos($v, ':') === false && strpos($v, 'active') === false && $v != ''){
    $res[] = $v;
  }
});
```

https://3v4l.org/JDFZg

Comment: What if the word in one of the final elements contains `:` or `active`?

Comment: @Qirel thats why i have mentioned `the solution is based on the provided input`